ASP.NET Core Identity endpoints missing
I'm brand new to ASP.NET Core Identity and I'm trying to get a working example project going.
I had a previous project that used .net Entity Core and the project was working with a controller and a postgres database for basic CRUD operations.
I wanted to add Identity Core though so I started following the tutorial on Learn Microsoft.
Apparently Identity Core is supposed to generate some endpoints automatically for me but when I view my Swagger API page only my endpoints I created on my Controller are showing up.
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ShopBack.Database;
using ShopBack.Database.Repositories;
using ShopBack.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services
    .AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>()
    .AddScoped<ICategoryRepository, CategoryRepository>()
    .AddScoped<ProductsService>()
    .AddScoped<CategoryService>()
    .AddScoped<LibraryContext>()
    .AddScoped<IShopUnitOfWork, ShopUnitOfWork>()
    .AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>()
    .AddControllers(options => options.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false)

    .AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);
    //https://gavilan.blog/2021/05/19/fixing-the-error-a-possible-object-cycle-was-detected-in-different-versions-of-asp-net-core/

builder.Services.AddDbContext<LibraryContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourConnectionName"));
    });

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
        options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("AppDb"));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services
        .AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IdentityUser>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// configure request pipeline
app.MapControllers();

app.UseCors (x => x
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
    );

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.MapIdentityApi<IdentityUser>();

app.Run();

The tutorial had me create this DbContext class for Identity:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ShopBack.Database;

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    { }
}

In my Program.cs file (as shown above), I'm adding:
builder.Services
            .AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IdentityUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

and
app.MapIdentityApi<IdentityUser>();

Which I thought would create my endpoints for me but they don't show up in Swagger for me:

I put an [Authorize] annotation on my /products API endpoint and try to make the call and it tells me I'm not authorized when before I would just get a list of products back so I know Identity is partially working.
Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

You are missing builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer(); in your program.cs. aspnet core has two flavour Controllers and minimal api Endpoints. Entity framework core identity default api is exposed as minimal api endpoints. Hence, you need to add  AddEndpointsApiExplorer. Following is a working program.cs

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

var builder = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder
    .Services
    .AddControllers(options => options.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false)
    .AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();


builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestApp"));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services
        .AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IdentityUser>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapControllers();

app.UseCors(x => x
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
    );

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapIdentityApi<IdentityUser>();

app.Run();




Thanks,
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer()
was the only thing I was missing.
